# Name for set difference operation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I have an operation on sets which seems fairly natural, is quite similar to the symmetric difference, and I don't know if it has been studied and/or named before. I'm going to call it *asymmetric difference* for now. I'm not aware of a name for the codomain of this operation either.

**Question 1.** Is there a name for the class of mappings from a set to the integers? These are like multisets but their multiplicities may be negative.

Given two sets, $A$ and $B$, their *asymmetric difference* is $\chi_A - \chi_B$, where $\chi$ means characteristic function.  If you then take absolute value, you get the symmetric difference.

**Question 2.** Is there an existing name for this operation?

For context, I'm using this operation to produce a signed imbalance statistic for two sets.  This statistic is the (signed) cardinality of the asymmetric difference divided by the cardinality of the union. It is equivalent to $\frac{|A-B| - |B-A|}{|A\cup B|}$, or $\epsilon_{AB} |A\triangle B|$ where $\triangle$ is symmetric difference and $\epsilon_{AB}$ is 1 if $A-B$ is larger than $B-A$ and -1 otherwise.

**Question 3.** Is there an existing name for this statistic?

Comment: The class of mappings $A\to \Bbb Z$ is typically denoted as the product (ring?) $\Bbb Z^A$.

Comment: @Gae.S. Ah yes, that is relevant. I'm asking if there is a name for the class $\{ \mathbb{Z}^A \text{ for all sets } A\}$